# Why this ummat is granted as best ummat ever of human history?

Tags: islamic-basis

So is there any special duty for this ummat? Can anyone please give quotation from hadith and Quran, thanks.

Comment: "this ummat is granted as best ummat ever of human history" can you cite that? I mean, where did you get that idea from? In my understanding we are a *just* Ummah according to this aya: "وكذلك جعلناكم أمة وسطاً لتكونوا شهداء على الناس ويكون الرسول عليكم شهيداً" English: "And thus we have made you a just community that you will be witnesses over the people and the Messenger will be a witness over you" [Surat Al-Baqarah:143](http://quran.com/2/143)

Comment: And Sayyid, can you also tell me how can we fulfill this duty!

Answer (score 1):

Allah said in Surah Aali-Imran 3:110 =

> You are the best Ummah raised for mankind. You enjoin what is right and
>   forbid what is wrong and believe in Allah . If only the People of the
>   Scripture had believed, it would have been better for them. Among them
>   are believers, but most of them are defiantly disobedient.

Allah has said we're the best BUT gives us the reason why.  That's **You enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong and believe in Allah**

Without this, we're not the best and we're not doing our duty towards humanity.